# Object accessing data - Nodejs

Tags: node.js

How to access location properties from the following code (JSON Structure) and assign the value in Nodejs.

```
{ pos : { lon : 30, lat : 30 } }
```

Thanks

Comment: This question needs more information. Are you asking about simple access or usage of those properties? Is this data coming from a file, http request/response, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the JSON in a string variable, you can use

```
var json = JSON.parse(theString);
```

And then acces it by

```
json.pos.lon;
```